# Finding specific regions in a matched regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a regex which matches a specific pattern in my data, which I then process using string maniplutation. The patterns consist of paretheses and full stops:

```
((((((.))))))(...(((((..).).)))).
```

My current regex:

```
(?:\([\(.]+\()(?:[^()]*\.+[^()]*)\)[\).]+\)
```

finds the longest possible match, which it then checks against a minimum value for opening and closing parentheses (which match) and a maximum value for dots.

However, I'm finding I'm having an issue - sometimes the longest match meets the criteria for minimum number of parentheses but has too many dots, and so doesn't extract the pattern, even though there is a stretch within the pattern that does meet the criteria.

I have no idea how to code for this! Is this a nested pattern problem, or can it be processed as a regular string?

Here is the section of my code dealing with this.

```py
def function_for_processing(file_name, dots, brackets):

    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith('(') or line.startswith('.') or line.startswith(')'):
                # Operate only on lines with bracket/dot annotation
                matches = re.finditer(r'(?:\([\(.]+\()(?:[^()]*\.+[^()]*)\)[\).]+\)', line)
                for match in matches:
                    loop_dots = re.findall(r'(?<=\()([^()]*\.{2}[^()]*)(?=\))', match.group(0))
                    internal_dots_removed = re.sub(r'(?<=\()([^()]*\.{2}[^()]*)(?=\))', '', match.group(0))

                    loop_count = sum([char == '.' for char in str(loop_dots)])

                    dot_count = internal_dots_removed.count(".")
                    opening_count = internal_dots_removed.count("(")
                    closing_count = internal_dots_removed.count(")")
                    if dot_count <= dots and opening_count == closing_count >= brackets and loop_count >= 3:
#Further processing continues...
```

An example:

if dots = 20 and brackets = 19

This data point:

```
(((((((((....(((.((..(((((.((((((((.(.(((((((((((((((.((((((..((......)))))))).))))))))))).)))).).))))....)))).)).)))....)))))...))).))))))
```

Which has 51 opening brackets, 51 closing brackets, and 31 dots (excluding the internal dots, which don't count towards the maximum) is passed over, but it contains an idea match:

```
(((((.((((((((.(.(((((((((((((((.((((((..((......)))))))).))))))))))).)))).).))))....)))).)).)))
```

Which has the minimum number of brackets either side of the internal dots which are equal, has below the maximum dots, and starts and ends with a bracket.

Comment: what is the use of `[^()]`, this also matches `a`

Comment: `\([\(.]+\(` means `(.)` is an illegal pattern? no need to escape inside `[]`: `\([(.]+\(`

Comment: Why all the extra capturing parenthesis. Like `((((((.))))))(...(((((..).).)))).` -> `(.)(...(((..).).)).`

Comment: The longest match requires testing all alternative paths that may not match the desired result.

Comment: That's just how the data looks, the goal is to find symmetrical patterns with as few dots as possible

Comment: Note that your regex can't count so it matches `(((.))))))`. There was a guy on SO who proposed _recursion simulation'_ regex. It works! It might be you're heading into recursion simulation: `(?s)(?=\()(?:(?=.*?\((?!.*?\1)(.*\)(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\)(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^(]*(?=\2)` https://regex101.com/r/SRZGf9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probably more efficient way to find the matches is to find the shortest match that meets the minimal brackets requirement, then expand that match outwards while it still meets the maximal dots requirement:

```py
import re

def find_matches(text, dots, brackets):
    # find shortest match with the required number of brackets
    match = re.search(rf'\((?:\.*\(){{{brackets-1}}}(?:\.*\)){{{brackets-1}}}\)', text)
    if match is None:
        return None
    
    # don't count dots in the very middle of the pattern
    internal_dots = len(re.search(r'(?<=\()\.*(?=\))', text).group())
    dots += internal_dots
    
    # iterate outwards until we reach the end of the string
    start, end = match.span()
    longest = match.group()
    
    if longest.count('.') > dots:
        return None
    
    while start > 0:
        start = text.rindex('(', 0, start)
        end = text.index(')', end+1)
        if start < 0 or end < 0:
            break
        next_longest = text[start:end+1]
        if next_longest.count('.') > dots:
            break
        longest = next_longest
    
    return longest

dots = 20
brackets = 19

texts = [
    '(((((((((....(((.((..(((((.((((((((.(.(((((((((((((((.((((((..((......)))))))).))))))))))).)))).).))))....)))).)).)))....)))))...))).))))))',
    ' .............((((.......(((...)))...(((((((...........)))))))((((.(((.(((((......((((......(((((((.((......))..))))))).....)))).....)))))))).))))))))'
]

for text in texts:
    result = find_matches(text, dots, brackets)
    if result is not None:
        print(f'{result.count("("):2d} brackets, {result.count("."):2d} dots : {result}')
    else:
        print('No matching string found')
```

Output:

```
37 brackets, 22 dots : (((((.((((((((.(.(((((((((((((((.((((((..((......)))))))).))))))))))).)))).).))))....)))).)).)))
No matching string found
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nick! This is great. I have one last question - can this handle when there are potentially multiple matches per line? I assume I could change the match variable to matches, and then loop through each match the same way.

Comment: @SJP yes, if there can be multiple matches per line, you'd need to use `re.finditer` in place of `re.search` and then iterate each match in the way I have done in the function.

Comment: Note that the computation of `internal_dots` would also then be on `match.group()` rather than `text`. In fact, you could change the current code to that too, and it would be slightly better.

Comment: I'm finding that this code is also not applying the dot maximum, eg:

.............((((.......(((...)))...(((((((...........)))))))((((.(((.(((((......((((......(((((((.((......))..))))))).....)))).....)))))))).)))))))).

this is the portion is extracted (which has 32 dots)
(.(((((......((((......(((((((.((......))..))))))).....)))).....))))))

Also, no matter what dots is update to, the output is identical! Do you know why this might be?

I also think the shortest match found with the initial regex also doesn't necessarily have less than 20 dots, so that might be the problem..

Comment: @SJP my apologies, I forgot to check that the initial match passed the `dots` test. I've corrected the code, see my edit.

Comment: Hey Nick! just wondering - rindex does not work on a re.match object it seems.
Can you reccommend a way to apply rindex to the match while also retaining the match info (start, end, etc)

Comment: `match.group().rindex()` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is by using the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, which supports both recursive and overlapping matches, both of which are useful to this problem. You can use the following regex to find nested `(xxx)` strings in your input:

```
\((?:\.|(?R))*\)
```

This matches:

- `\(` : a `(`
- `(?:\.|(?R))*` : either a `.` or the whole pattern, some number of times
- `\)` : a `)`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PHCFYt/1)

We can find all overlapping matches of the input string, then compare the number of `(` and `.` to the required minimum and maximum values to find all matching solutions:

```py
import regex

def find_longest_match(text, dots, brackets):
    pattern = regex.compile(r'\((?:\.|(?R))*\)')
    
    # don't count dots in the very middle of the pattern
    internal_dots = len(regex.search(r'(?<=\()\.*(?=\))', text).group())
    dots += internal_dots
    
    # search through matches, starting with shortest
    longest = None
    for match in pattern.findall(text, overlapped=True)[::-1]:
        if match.count('(') < brackets:
            continue
        # found match with minimal number of brackets, does it have too many dots?
        if match.count('.') > dots:
            break
        longest = match
    
    return longest

dots = 20
brackets = 19

texts = [
    '(((((((((....(((.((..(((((.((((((((.(.(((((((((((((((.((((((..((......)))))))).))))))))))).)))).).))))....)))).)).)))....)))))...))).))))))',
    ' .............((((.......(((...)))...(((((((...........)))))))((((.(((.(((((......((((......(((((((.((......))..))))))).....)))).....)))))))).))))))))'
]

for text in texts:
    result = find_longest_match(text, dots, brackets)
    if result is not None:
        print(f'{result.count("("):2d} brackets, {result.count("."):2d} dots : {result}')
    else:
        print('No matching string found')
```

Output (note the number of dots includes the internal dots, which are not counted towards the maximum):

```
37 brackets, 22 dots : (((((.((((((((.(.(((((((((((((((.((((((..((......)))))))).))))))))))).)))).).))))....)))).)).)))
No matching string found
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about this. If there will be many many lines containing the pattern, is the approach still appropriate? There are possibly millions of lines to check for the best match. Also, is it possible to simply isolate the single longest match that satisfies the minimum and maximum values for brackets and dots?

Comment: @SJP regex is never going to be fast. You would probably get a better result by finding the middle of the string and iterating your way outwards (hmmm... might post that as another answer). In terms of finding the longest match, I would iterate in the opposite direction to the code in the question until I found the first match which met the criteria, since that will be the longest match.

Comment: If you could post as a separate answer, that would be great! Thanks for your help, really appreciate it

Comment: @SJP I've posted another answer...

Comment: @SJP Just for completeness, I've modified this answer to only return the longest match. It now gives the same result as the other function.